# Uncaught Error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found

Tags: php, websocket, composer-php, ratchet

> Uncaught Error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in
>   D:\webs\Live_Chat\bin\server.php:12.

**File Directory**

```
- webs
   - Live_Chat
     - classes
       - Chat.php
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyApp\\": "classes"
    }
},
"require": {
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.2"
}
```

}

I have put Chat.php in classes folder and set root of autoload JSON as "classes".

I'm using first time any web socket. Please help.

Comment: Where is your `composer.json` file in your architecture?

Comment: In Live_Chat folder

Comment: It is in the root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting the Chat.php file in another folder name src.
And then replace this code in the composer.json "MyApp\": "src".